# Is it possible to make the user enter a date in an exact date format using DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, spring-mvc

I have a date picker on one form, I want to have the user enter the date with the century, and not allow the date to be inserted without the century.

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```

However, this still allows the user to enter 1/1/91.

Comment: You need a client side script. I use this one: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I want to have it done using model validation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ApplyFormatInEditMode:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```